# Excel conditional field setup

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel (2003) I'd like to setup conditional field data population logic.

For instance, if B2 = 'text string1' then C2 = 'number string1' OR B2 = 'text string2' then C2 = 'number string2' OR ...

Make sense? How can I do this?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're looking to setup a formula that populates a cell with different values based on the values of a different cell?

Answer (score 0):

In cell C2: 
`=IF(B2='textstring1','numberstring1',IF(B2='textstring2','numberstring2','return in other cases'))`

If you don't use the last statement then the formula will return FALSE in any other instances. If you want to return nothing use `""` as the last statement

If there can only be two textstrings then this can be simplified as 
`=IF(B2='textstring1','numberstring1','numberstring2')`

Comment: Thanks for the reply CLockeWOrk. When I tried this it won't let me save it. An error box pops up (The formula you typed contains and error) with the following;
IF(logical_test,[value_if_true],[value_if_false]
I am not really looking for true/false...

Comment: Try replacing the commas (`,`s) with semicolons (`;`s).

Comment: True @Scott, i keep forgetting locality

Answer (score 0):

How many possible text values are there? If you have more than a few then a lookup table would be the best approach

Set up a two column table somewhere on the worksheet (or another worksheet) with possible text in the first column and required numbers in the second....and name this Table1

Now for your formula you can use this in C2

`=VLOOKUP(B2,Table1,2,FALSE)`

if you want to account for errors or no match add an IFERROR function, e.g.

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Table1,2,FALSE),"No match")`